# Why won't the username appear in my payload when making a post request?

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, debugging, axios

I'm trying to see `username` and `email` columns that of which are SQL db columns in my payload but for some reason it doesn't show up.  I'm using React as frontend and Laravel as backend and for some reason, I'm not seeing them.

What could I be doing wrong?

Here's `User.php` model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'username', 'email', 'password',
    ];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
];

public function posts() {
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
}
```

Here's `Posts.php` model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['body'];

    public function user() {
        $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

}
```

Here's `PostController.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function create(Request $request, Post $post) {
        // create post
        $createdPost = $request->user()->posts()->create([
            'body' => $request->body
        ]);

        // return response
        return response()->json($createdPost);
    }
}
```

Here's `web.php`:

```
Auth::routes();

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::post('/posts', 'PostController@create');
});
```

Here's my post request:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        body: '',
        posts: []
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // this.postData();
    axios.post('/posts', {
        body: this.state.body
    }).then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.setState({
           posts: [...this.state.posts, response.data]
        });
    });

    this.setState({
        body: ''
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the `return` key :).

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    ^^^^^^
}
```

Comment: I always had this problem when starting using Laravel. Well, still happens to me once in a while, but not as often as before lol.

Comment: wow... I feel like an idiot, I was stuck on this for so long.  thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are not passing the foreign key correctly,

```php
protected $fillable = ['body', 'user_id'];

public function user()
{
    $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
}
```

Comment: Tried that, still encountering the same issue :(

Comment: can you do a dd or print_r($request->body); in you PostController?

Comment: just ran `print_r($request->body);` in PostController and this is what I got: `{data: "some info{"body":"some info","user_id":1,"updated_…8:56","created_at":"2019-05-01 23:18:56","id":73}", status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …} `.  I just don't understand how I don't see `username` and `email`, it makes no sense.

Comment: try calling `print_r($createdPost);` just before emitting response;

Comment: got the same response

Comment: If i am getting what you want is user name from the post your created right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192692/discussion-between-aditya-thakur-and-mr-test).